# Open new tab while alert is present Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a chrome window with an open alert. I don't want to accept or dismiss the alert but open a new tab while the alert is present. But trying to do anything with the selenium driver raises a `UnexpectedAlertPresentException`.

What can be done to ignore the alert and open a new tab?

Answer (score 2):

You can handle Alert by try-catch, Where its raised:

```
try {
    driver.switchTo().alert();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Further you can go forward with tab operations.

By come back on this original alert window, You can Accept or Dismiss it:

```
try {
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: But trying any tab operations will keep raising the exception. So even if I put my tab operations in catch block it will keep throwing exceptions everytime I try an operation.

Comment: Have you tried this scenario with try-catch ? In my solution, you are performing operation for alert without accept and cancel it. And driver got it.

Comment: Yes I tried this. The operations required to open a new tab or switch a tab are performed on the driver and whenever an operation is tried, it throws a new exception.

Comment: what is new exception ?

Comment: Its always going to be the same exception. I just mean every attempt at any operation will keep throwing the exception.